# Performance of swift extensions on primitive types

Tags: swift, optimization, extension-methods

I am wondering if there would be any performance difference between the following in `swift`:

```
let x = 42.42
print(floor(x))
```

and

```
let x = 42.42
extension Double {
  func myFloor() -> Double {
    return floor(self)
  }
}
print(x.myFloor())
```

Comment: Well the second one has a compile time error (non-void return in a method declared to return void), and causes a runtime error (infinite recursion, because `floor` refers to the instance method, not `Darwin.floor` or `Glibc.floor` as intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler inlines the code in the second case and produces the same machine code. [You can see for yourself, here.](https://godbolt.org/g/5gGst7)

[image]