# Is it expensive to create extensions on types (ex on String)

Tags: swift, extension-methods

In swift ,say we are adding some string manupulation function , which is being called only once but considering the future uses, I am planning to add an extension to strings type

I just wanted to know is it a good way of coding?because this extention will be avilable for all the strings within the project,

Comment: hi, there is detailed explanation here, https://www.natashatherobot.com/using-swift-extensions/

Comment: The entire Swift Standard Library is heavily based on extensions. So it cannot be that expensive 

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558276/performance-of-swift-extensions-on-primitive-types, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895972/swift-extension